# Working with observables with repeated data

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an Observable with data.

```
 comments: Observable<Comment>
```

Then I call the getComments() method.

When I scroll to the finish of the list, I call the getComments method, to get the next older comments.

But if new comments are added on the time I was scrolling down, I will get the oldest comments again because the news comments are added at the start.

Actually I am using this:

```
this.comments.concat(<Comment[]>data)
    .distinct(x => x.id)
    .subscribe()
```

But I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Please let me know if the answer solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `BehaviorSubject`. Everytime got new comments, concat the data in. For example:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

comments = new BehaviorSubject([]);

getComments() {

  // data from api
  const newComments$ = of([
    { id: 6, name: 'f' },
    { id: 7, name: 'g' }
  ]);

  zip(newComments$, this.comments)
    .subscribe(([newComm, oldComm]) => {
      this.comments.next(newComm.concat(oldComm));
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    // since it's a behavior subject, you can subscribe like observable
    this.comments.subscribe(x => {
       // do whatever you want
    })
}
```